# How to detect a Web server and localserver?

Tags: php

Is there a way to detect if the site is running under a web server and local server.

Comment: what's the difference? isn't "local" server a web-server? but what? an ftp one?

Comment: @closevoter, what is not real about this question?

Comment: I assume you want to distinguish between a local testing server and a public one, right? Both would be "web servers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']

Comment: +1, check that variable and match it against the ip ranges that are reserved for local/private use like "192.168.*.*" or "10.*.*.*" etc, etc.

Comment: There's also `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` if the devel and live servers have different names. Might be somewhat more portable, especially if the live server is actually a cluster with multiple IPs